# Creating a 2D string array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

So basically I am trying to read from a huge text file and need to store the data in a `2D` `string` array in `C`. But I am getting a **`segmentation fault`** every time.

Here is the code I use to create the array:

```
Y = 3
X = 12
char ***some_array=NULL;
some_array = (char ***)malloc(Y * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i=0; i<Y; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<X; j++){
            some_array[i] = (char **)malloc(X * sizeof(char *));
            some_array[i][j] = (char *)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
        }
```

So technically, I am creating a 3D char array for this means. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: *So technically, I am creating a 3D char array...*  No, you're creating a one-dimensional array of pointers to multiple one-dimensional arrays of pointers to multiple one-dimensional arrays of `char[16]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the allocation of `some_array[i] = (char **)malloc(X * sizeof(char *));` from the inner most loop to the outer loop. Moreover, you [should not cast the malloc return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). For the final code:

```
Y = 3
X = 12
char ***some_array = NULL;
some_array = malloc(Y * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < Y; i++){
        some_array[i] = malloc(X * sizeof(char *));
        for (int j = 0; j < X; j++){
            some_array[i][j] = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you can create a statically allocated array:

```
char some_array [X][Y][16];
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is in your loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<Y; i++) {
    some_array[i] = (char **)malloc(X * sizeof(char *));
    for (int j=0; j<X; j++){
        some_array[i][j] = (char *)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

You are supposed to allocate memory to `some_array[i]` outside the inner loop.